# Firebase hosting - prevent user from seeing my code

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Firebase web hosting

I have uploaded to the public folder 3 items:

1. index.html
2. js folder
3. css folder

I notice that I can browse to the folders and actually see the js file or css under these folders. I want to prevent it.
I tried to put .htaccess but it does not seem to have any effect at all.
I need your assistance how should I prevent directory browsing?

Comment: Firebase Hosting doesn't support directory browsing.  It will show your 404 page if you use a path that points to a directory without an index.html.  Are you sure you're looking at the right thing?

Comment: Yes I am sure.
After login I am trying to access to the js file(myAPP - sample name)
https://myAPP.firebaseapp.com/js/index.js
And I am able to see the entire file.

Comment: That's not directory browsing.  It's just serving up content as normal.  Why are you expecting content that you deployed to ever be invisible to direct access.

Comment: Can avoid users from seen it ? I do not want them to see my code.

Comment: That's impossible.  Web sites have always worked like this.

Comment: Well I have to think of something, surely I can not let users option to guess and see my code.
Thank you Doug for your input on this.
Eran